# How to decompose Bloch sphere rotations $e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}(\cos(\phi)\sigma_x + \sin(\phi)\sigma_y)}$ in terms of $R_x,R_y,R_z$?

Tags: mathematics, bloch-sphere

I learned a formula to represent the rotation around bloch sphere:

$\theta_{\phi} = e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}(\cos(\phi)\sigma_x + \sin(\phi)\sigma_y)}$

So that $\pi_0$ is the gate $X$ and $\pi_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is the gate $Y$.

My question is: how do we get this formula to represent the rotation gate? If we have a gate, say $\pi_{\frac{\pi}{6}}$, how do we use the rotation gates like $R_x$, $R_y$, or $R_Z$ to represent the gate?

Comment: Does this help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere#Rotation_operators_about_the_Bloch_basis ?

Comment: To clarify: are you asking how of to decompose $\theta_\phi$ in terms of $R_x$, $R_y$ and $R_z$, or are you asking how to write (say) $R_x$ in terms of $\theta_\phi$?

Comment: I am asking the first case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at
$$
\cos(\phi)\sigma_x+\sin(\phi)\sigma_y
$$
we can write this as
$$
\cos(\phi)\sigma_x+\sin(\phi)\sigma_y=R_z(2\phi)\sigma_x=R_z(\phi)\sigma_xR_z(-\phi).
$$
(I'm taking the convention that $R_z(\phi)=e^{-i\phi/2}$). The above equation is easier to verify from right to left, using the anticommutation properties of $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z$, meaning that $\sigma_xR_z(-\phi)=R_z(\phi)\sigma_x$, followed by the fact that $R_z(\phi)R_z(\phi)=R_z(2\phi)$.

Now, you can write that
$$
\theta_\phi=e^{-i\theta R_z(\phi)\sigma_xR_z(-\phi)/2}
$$
Remember that $Ue^{-iHt}U^\dagger=e^{-iUHU^\dagger t}$.
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\theta_\phi&=R_z(\phi)e^{-i\theta\sigma_x/2}R_z(-\phi) \\
&=R_z(\phi)R_x(-\theta)R_z(-\phi)
\end{align*}

Comment: In the original equation: $\theta_{\phi} = e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}(\cos(\phi)\sigma_x + \sin(\phi)\sigma_y)}$, there is no `-`.

The final result should be:
\begin{align*}
\theta_\phi&=R_z(\phi)e^{i\theta\sigma_x/2}R_z(-\phi) \\
&=R_z(\phi)R_x(-\theta)R_z(-\phi)
\end{align*}
where I add a minus sign to the middle term, right?

Comment: @peachnuts Yes, thank you. corrected.